# Changing properties of multiple <video> tags from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I can change the source of an HTML5 video at runtime like this:

```
<video autoplay></video>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = "http://new/url";
</script>
```

But if I have multiple video's on the page how do I refer to each of them in the script and access their individual attributes?

Am I able to provide a name string for the video entities? I am expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
<video name="video0" autoplay></video>
<viedo name="video1" autoplay></video>
<script>
    video0.src = "http://first/url";
    video1.src = "http://second/url";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either assign the elements a unique `ID` attribute and use `document.getElementById()`, or use `document.getElementsByTagName('video')` to retrieve all `video`s on the page.

Comment: Suddenly, everyone forgets there is `document.getElementsByName`.

Comment: Thanks. jQuery seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: @infact I agree, jQuery is expensive if all you want to do is access some DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

This gets an HTMLCollection of all `video` tags

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
```

You can select them by name using:

```
var videos = document.querySelector('video[name="video0"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to retrieve them by tag name with pure JS:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i] // the i-th video
}
```

If you're open to jQuery you can do the same with jQuery:

```
var videos = $('video');
videos.each(function (index, videoElement) {
    // this refers to the current video.
});
```

Comment: In the array will the video's be in the same order in which they appear in the HTML?

Comment: @Asad How is that related to my answer though?

Comment: @Asad Yes I wrote this because below I have a jQuery example and the above uses plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an `id`. To easily access the nodes I'd recommend using [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/):

```
<video id="video0" autoplay></video>
<video id="video1" autoplay></video>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var video0 = $('#video0');
        var video1 = $('#video1');
        video0.attr('src', 'http://first/url');
        video1.attr('src', 'http://second/url');
    });
</script>
```